# Displaying firebase realtime database entries using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the firebase realtime database to display information that users on my web app can submit. A submit page is in use where particular users submit info to my database, where (this is where i'm stuck) that info is displayed on the said persons profile page.

[This is what the database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNAIz.png)

[This is what the submit form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vS5w.png)

This is the submit JS

```js
function writeUserData() {

  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var userDisplayName = user.displayName;
  var userid = user.uid;
  var getFieldID = document.getElementById('id_field').value;
  var getFieldName = document.getElementById('name_field').value;
  var getFieldDate = document.getElementById('dateField').value;
  var getFieldTime = document.getElementById('timeField').value;
  var getFieldDesc = document.getElementById('desc').value;


  const db = firebase.database();

  

 db.ref('teachers/' + getFieldID).push({
    student_UID: userid,
    student_displayName: userDisplayName,
    teacher_ID: getFieldID,
    teacher_name: getFieldName,
    date: getFieldDate,
    time: getFieldTime,
    description: getFieldDesc
 }); 
  

};
```

How do I then get that user data and display it on a particular page? I've had a look through *most* of the documentation on firebase for web and can't find anything.

Now with the DB, multiple submissions under the same 'id' can be submitted and created with the .push function. My issue is retrieving the data and being able to display **all** submissions under a particular child (eg test1, test 2) on the webpage.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to save a copy of the reference.

```
const teacherRef = db.ref('teachers/' + getFieldID).push({
    student_UID: userid,
    student_displayName: userDisplayName,
    teacher_ID: getFieldID,
    teacher_name: getFieldName,
    date: getFieldDate,
    time: getFieldTime,
    description: getFieldDesc
}); 

console.log('teacherRef key', teacherRef.key);

teacherRef.once('value', snapshot => {
  const value = snapshot.val();

  console.log('saved value', value);
})
```